# Video scrolling effect only works until a certain image

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are 100 frames and it only goes until the 28th frame. This happens when you use the mouse scroller.

But if you try using the scroll bar and go down, you can see that goes to 100 frames.

How can I make the mouse scroller work the same way? I noticed every scroll is 100px up or down which means that for every 100 pixels will show 1 frame.

How can I modify my code to make this work smoothly?

Here is my code and here the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dethdoll/29qL7/):

```
var counter = 0;
var scrollArray = []; // array that will have 2 top positions to compare with to see if it is scrolling up or down

$(window).scroll(function() {        
    var top = $(this).scrollTop();       
    if(top > 1 && top < 13000) { // where I want the video to start playing              
        scrollArray.push(top); // pushes values into the array       
        // conditional for keeping 2 values in the array            
        if(scrollArray.length > 1) {
            if(scrollArray[0] < scrollArray[1]) { // 
                counter++;  
            }
            else {
                counter--;
            }   
            scrollArray = [];            
        }
        else {          
            var addCeros = (4 - String(counter).length);

            if(counter <= 100 && counter >= 1) {
                var numPic = ''; 
                for (var i = 0; i < addCeros; i++) {
                    numPic += '0';  
                }
                numPic += counter;
                $('#slide2 img').attr('src', 'http://360langstrasse.sf.tv/tutorial/shared/street/vid-'+numPic+'.jpg');  
                $('#slide2 span').text('http://360langstrasse.sf.tv/tutorial/shared/street/vid-'+numPic+'.jpg');
            }                
        }
    }        
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.onscroll` really fires a lot of events, so you need to throttle it updating the image. If you look in the net panel of firebug, you can see a lot of aborted image requests.
Throttling means you will need to allow the user to skip frames. So I rewrote your handler to tie in to the current scroll percentage.

http://jsfiddle.net/29qL7/1/

```
var debounceTimer,
    throttleTimestamp = 0;

function throttleScroll() {
    var dur = 100;
    clearTimeout(debounceTimer);
    if (+new Date - throttleTimestamp > dur) {
        showSlide();
        throttleTimestamp = +new Date;
    } else {
        debounceTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            showSlide();
            throttleTimestamp = +new Date;
        }, dur);
    }
}

function showSlide() {

    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
        docHeight = $(document).height(),
        winHeight = $(window).height(),
        scrollPercent = Math.ceil((scrollTop / (docHeight - winHeight)) * 100),
        fileName = "00"+scrollPercent;

    if(scrollPercent<10)fileName = "000"+scrollPercent;
    if(scrollPercent==100)fileName = "0"+scrollPercent;
    if(scrollTop>0){
        $('#slide2 img').attr('src', 'http://360langstrasse.sf.tv/tutorial/shared/street/vid-' + fileName + '.jpg');
    }

}

$(window).scroll(throttleScroll);
```

Comment: No worries :) If you want a seamless experience, have a look at preloading the images.

Comment: I will take a look into that as well :) Thanks a million!